# Eclipse plugin - delay in writing to console

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I'm developing a Eclipse plugin that reads from and writes to the console. I expect the following code to flash an alert window with "Hello World" on it.

```
public void run(IAction action) {
        ConsoleCommands.writeToConsole("Hello World!");
        Alert(ConsoleCommands.readConsole());
    }
```

However, the alert simply shows blank. Some investigation showed that the read was happening before the write (the display on the console was fine, just the alert was showing the previous state of the console) so I tried,

```
public void run(IAction action) {
        ConsoleCommands.writeToConsole("Hello Wolrd!");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Alert(ConsoleCommands.readConsole());
    }
```

in case there was a threading issue, but this simply delays the writing to the console as well. Any ideas what is happening?

----EDIT-----

In case it's useful, here's the code for the methods...

```
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.ConsolePlugin;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.IConsole;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.IConsoleManager;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.MessageConsole;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.MessageConsoleStream;

import org.eclipse.jface.action.IAction;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.ConsolePlugin;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.IConsole;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.IConsoleManager;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.MessageConsole;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.MessageConsoleStream;


public class ConsoleCommands {

    private static MessageConsole findConsole(String name) {
        ConsolePlugin plugin = ConsolePlugin.getDefault();
        IConsoleManager conMan = plugin.getConsoleManager();
        IConsole[] existing = conMan.getConsoles();
        for (int i = 0; i < existing.length; i++)
            if (name.equals(existing[i].getName()))
                return (MessageConsole) existing[i];
        // no console found, so create a new one
        MessageConsole myConsole = new MessageConsole(name, null);
        conMan.addConsoles(new IConsole[] { myConsole });
        return myConsole;
    }

    public static String readConsole() {
        MessageConsole myConsole = findConsole("Joe's Console");
        IDocument doc = myConsole.getDocument();
        return doc.get();
    }

    public static MessageConsole writeToConsole(String output) {
        MessageConsole myConsole = findConsole("Joe's Console");
        MessageConsoleStream out = myConsole.newMessageStream();
        out.println(output);
        return myConsole;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try writing to the console using `myConsole.getDocument().set(output)` instead of using the stream.

I don't know if this is recommended practice but it solved the problem for us...